# ABP Framework Bookstore out-of-the-box : Unhandled exception (ports)

Tags: abp

I receive the following when launching the ABP Frameworks Bookstore sample app after template download and install. I suspect my firewall is blocking the ports configured by default. Anyone run into this?

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(string host, int port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)a

Comment: I also have the same issue. Anyone?